# load into the input file the image that was chosen before

Tags: javascript, html, image, upload

I created three input files in my html form:

```
<td><input type="file" name="image_url1" /></td> -one of the three
```

I uploaded and saved the filenames on the server.

Now, i want to edit the form. That means -> edit the input file.
How can i load into the input file the image that was chosen before?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but if you saved the image on the server, how about getting the URL to  that image from the server ?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean, set the value of the `input` tag to the name of the file that was uploaded, you can't.  This is by design.  You wouldn't want a page to be able to specify (maybe in a hidden tag) what file it wanted to upload from your machine, would you?

The closest you could get would be to display the name of the file that was just uploaded and show another `input` tag in case the user wanted to upload a different file.